# TDLib - send message to other person by his phone number

Tags: java, telegram, tdlib

I am using the TDLib API of telegram.

I know the receivers phone number.

How to send a message to him, no matter whether there is already a chat or not?

How to get the chat id?

Answer (score 0):

Using official client, you can add them as a contact and message after that.

Thus, you need TDLib AddContact method and everything related to that, like GetContacts or SearchContacts.